# Ruby: A check for immediate value?

Tags: ruby

I am storing simple values (basic datatypes) into a hash, and I am calling `dup` on the value prior to avoid affecting the original object (like a snapshot). I wish not to do `dup` in the event of an immediate value, and want to simply store it as is. Is it possible to determine if an object/value is immediate?

i.e. (12, 13, 14 are immediate)

```
[12] pry(#<Table2Spec::TestTable>)> 1.dup
TypeError: can't dup Fixnum
from (pry):12:in `dup'
[13] pry(#<Table2Spec::TestTable>)> :f.dup
TypeError: can't dup Symbol
from (pry):13:in `dup'
[14] pry(#<Table2Spec::TestTable>)> true.dup
TypeError: can't dup TrueClass
from (pry):14:in `dup'
[16] pry(#<Table2Spec::TestTable>)> 's'.dup
=> "s"
```

According to the documentation:

```
Immediate values are not passed by reference but are passed by value: nil, true, false, Fixnums, Symbols, and some Floats.
```

Comment: Ruby 2.4.0 allows duping of immediate objects (although the docs haven’t been completely updated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowing from Python, EAFP (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission):

```
hash[key] =
  begin
    value.dup
  rescue TypeError
    value
  end
```

Comment: Ruby 2.2.1 The one liner version `value = "hello"; p begin value.dup rescue TypeError; "Opps" end`  => `"Opps"`.  If you expand the expression in multiple lines, then => `"hello"`

Comment: Thank you both very much. I will use this logic, but not on one line to avoid the issue @yeyo has described. There is a C function rb_special_const_p that returns true if the value is not a pointer. This will cause the #dup method to raise TypeError. This satisfies my needs.

Comment: @yeyo: You are completely correct, I didn't think this through :)

Comment: Regarding @Matt's comment, though a bit klutzy, how about `def immediate?(obj); begin; e = obj.dup; e.object.id == obj.object.id; rescue TypeError; true; end`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland That would work, but is an overkill for OP's stated purpose (stuff a value into a hash, with a divorced reference if reference value).

Comment: Yes, of course. I forgot your code was not to determine if a value is immediate, but to dup values that can be duped. It still does that, and can be viewed as a way of accommodating earlier versions of Ruby.

Comment: If you are using rails 5 you can check the duplicable? method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/TrueClass.html#method-i-duplicable-3F

Comment: @Cary: Thanks for your solution. However, both answers lay the assumption that the result of dup determines if the object is immediate or not: There may be objects that will not spawn a duplicate object (such as singletons) that would not be be classed as immediate values in the same sense as rb_special_const_p.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend this solution but I am putting this here:

```
MyProject/
ext
└── core
    ├── extconf.rb
    └── core.c
```

**core.c**

```
#include <ruby.h>

VALUE Core = Qnil;

void Init_core();
VALUE method_core_is_immediate(VALUE self, VALUE obj);

void Init_core() {
  Core = rb_define_module("Core");
  rb_define_singleton_method(Core, "is_immediate_value?", method_core_is_immediate, 1);
}

VALUE method_core_is_immediate(VALUE self, VALUE obj) {
  if (rb_special_const_p(obj)) return (int)RUBY_Qtrue;
    return (int)RUBY_Qfalse;
}
```

**extconf.rb:**

```
require 'mkmf'
extension_name = 'core'
dir_config(extension_name)
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

**ruby:**

```
require 'core'

Core.is_immediate_value?(nil)  #true
Core.is_immediate_value?(true) #true
Core.is_immediate_value?(:symb) #true
Core.is_immediate_value?("string") #false
```

This may be of use to someone. After studying for a few hours I made this and it appears to work (just a way to invoke rb_special_const_p). It would be useful if there were a way to validate immediate values using the ruby standard library.